# How to make date-fns's format function return times in UTC (not local time)?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

Is there a way to get the following code to output hours in UTC time?

```js
format(date, 'MM/dd/yy hh:mm a') // outputs 01-17-2020 03:25 PM
```

How would I make output `01-17-2020 11:25 PM`?

Comment: You could use moment.js (https://momentjs.com/). It gives UTC time.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

There is a function

```
date.toUTCString(); // Returns "Sat, 02 Mar 2019 13:00:00 GMT"
```

Or there are individual functions like `. getUTCMonth()`

So you could do this with

```
console.log(`${date.getUTCMonth()}/${date.getUTCDay()}/${date.getUTCYear()} ${date.getUTCHour()}:${date.getUTCMinute()}`)
```

More information here: https://dev.to/mcapodici/javascript-dates-2dbj

Or, better still, you could use momentjs, which has a UTC mode, like this:

```
moment().format();     // 2013-02-04T10:35:24-08:00
moment.utc().format(); // 2013-02-04T18:35:24+00:00
```

Comment: Thanks Mikkel! Would definitely recommend using native JS or momentjs. You could also use `formatToTimeZone` from [`date-fns-timezone`](https://github.com/prantlf/date-fns-timezone#readme), but it's out of sync with `date-fns` right now.

Comment: The question is about date-fns specifically. This answer is about date formatting in JavaScript in general.